# Alternative to MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI for multiple videos

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm basically trying to view all the photos and videos in a given folder from my Camera app, when the preview is clicked. So basically the user will view the latest photo while having the ability to swipe to view other photos that were previously taken. I have achieved this for photos, but am unable to do so for videos. There is only one URI related to videos in MediaStore class called `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` that displays a given video (no way to access other photos/videos) unlike `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` which is used to open the gallery while having access to multiple photos. Is there any other way I can show all the videos in a given folder while focusing on the latest video?

**Code to open gallery**

```
    public void openGallery() {

        String mediaId = "";

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        final String fileName = config.getLatestMediaFile().getName();

        Uri mediaUri;

        if(videoCapturer.isLatestMediaVideo()){
            mediaUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else {
            mediaUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "MediaURI: " + mediaUri.getPath());

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                mediaUri, projection, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                if(name.equals(fileName)){
                    mediaId = cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)));
                    break;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        if(!mediaId.equals("")){
            mediaUri = mediaUri.buildUpon()
                    .authority("media")
                    .appendPath(mediaId)
                    .build();
        }

        Log.d("TagInfo","Uri:  "+mediaUri);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mediaUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```